# How to enable a button/combobox/textbox items while clicking an another button Visual C++

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I am doing a small project in Visual C++. I am new to VC++. I am wondering, how can I enable a button or combobox or textbox items by clicking an another button in the same form?

Here in my form, I disabled the combo boxes for Power Line Frequency, Maximum Range, Measurement Rate Textbox, Apply button and Set parameters button.

The thing I have to do is enable the set parameters button when I click Init Button, and when I click Set Parameters button, the combo boxes for Power Line Frequency, Maximum Range, Measurement Rate Textbox, Apply button has to be enabled and finally, when I click the apply button, the values have to be updated in their respective fields and these combo boxes, textbox and apply has to be disabled.

Can anyone help me please to do these things?

Thanks in advance! Sorry, I am unable to upload the Image.

Comment: You've added a tag relating to windows forms, which is only available with C++/CLI (Microsoft's extensions for Common Language Runtime interop). If so, then this is *not* C++ (and the `c++-cli` and `winform` tags should be added and the `c++` tag removed).

Comment: I'm not sure where you problem is. Double-clicking the button causes an event handler skeleton to appear, in which you enable the stuff (`myControlName->Enabled = true;`)...